# Is there a way to use previous row value in pandas' apply function when previous value is iteratively summed ?or an efficient way?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, apply

I have a dataframe with some columns and I would like to apply the following transformation in an efficient manner.

Given  the Dataframe below:

```py
   C    D
 ===========
  Nan  10
  0  22 
  2  280
  4  250
  6  270
```

It should be transformed in such a way I can get the following output:

```py
   C    D
 ===========
  Nan  10
  0  22 
  2  280
  6  252
  12 276
```

Note that:

**C[i]** = **C[i]** + **C[i - 1]** + ... + **C[0]**

and

**D[i]** = **D[i]** + **C[i - 1]**

NaN values should be filtered.

Thx!

Comment: `rolling(2).sum()` and `shift()`

Comment: Why the last value of `D` is 280? It should be `270+6` 276 as per your logic.

Comment: yes, edited! i'm sorry!

Comment: Did you change the logic for `C`?  :(( Checkout my answer.

Comment: i'm sorry, you're write for the first version! i made a mistake, the value C have to change like a foor loop with the previous value, sorry again, and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['C'] = df['C'].cumsum()
df['D'] = df['D'].add(df['C'].shift(1).fillna(0))
```

Output:

```
      C      D
0   NaN      10.0
1   0.0      22.0
2   2.0     280.0
3   6.0     252.0
4   12.0    276.0
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you need:

```
df['C'] = df['C'].add(df['C'].shift(1).fillna(0))
df['D'] = df['D'].add(df['C'].shift(1).fillna(0))
```

Output:

```
       C       D
0   NaN      10.0
1   0.0      22.0
2   2.0     280.0
3   6.0     252.0
4   10.0    276.0
```

Comment: Feel free to [`accept`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) the answer. @joão-machado